# how to merge multiple auto search fields into one in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

```
MarketedProgramService.getMarketedPrograms().then(function( programs ) {
        $scope.programs = [];
        var userPrograms = $filter("filter")( programs, 
MarketedProgramService.userHasAccessToProgram.bind( null, UserProfile ) );
        //userPrograms.unshift( defaultProgram );

        // Exclude FirstComp/Maverick programs
        angular.forEach( userPrograms, function( program ) {
            if( program.mbu != "FC" ) {
                $scope.programs.push( program );
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain clearly.

Comment: the above one is one service and below one  is another service.I want to merge both

Comment: EligibilityService.getEligibility( getEligibilityParams() ).then(function( result ) {

   $scope.wcClassCodes = result.wcClassCodes;
   $scope.boClassCodes = result.bopClassCodes;
   $scope.states = result.states;
   $scope.selected.state = result.defaultState || "";
   $scope.setAvailableLines( result.availableLines );

  });

Comment: We need more specific information of your purpose. Could you post your html part where use this code?